# How do i acess DoubleBuffer[] from java in JNI

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, buffer

This is almost like 2D array. Each slot of the array is a DoubleBuffer.

Before when I do single Buffer, I used this in JNI:
Assume my JNI method take in a DoubleBuffer

```
double *dBuf = env->GetDirectBufferAddress(env, buf);
```

and then just indexing with simply using dBuf[i] => where i is index.
Let say I want to pass in an array of FloatBuffer, how do i indexing in to the slot and allocate data

can i say

```
double **dBuf = env->GetDirectBufferAddress(env, buf); ??
```

Help pls
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you can't. You have to obtain each element of the Java array with `GetObjectArrayElement(),` and then access each element as a `DoubleBuffer` using its API via JNI as usual.

Comment: you are correct i just solved it the way you mention here. thanks